# How to determine the existence of all subsets of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given

1. The definition of *subset*;
2. The axiom of power set: *for any set $S$, there exists a set $\wp$ such that $X \in \wp$ if and only if $X\subseteq S$*

we know what a subset *is* and what a power set *contains*.

In a simple case where a set $A$ is supposed to exist, with $A=\{a, b, c\}$, we know what is and what is not a subset of $A$:

$\{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{a,c\}, \emptyset$ and $A$ are subsets of $A$ and anything different is not.

> $\wp(A)=\big\{\{a\}, \{b\}, \{c\}, \{a, b\}, \{b,c\}, \{a,c\}, \{a, b, c\}, \emptyset\big\}$.

However the mere definition of something (and consequently it's recognition as such) does not guarantee its existence. $\emptyset$ and $A$ seem like the only subsets whose existence is immediate.

In other words, I know what a power set contains, but how do I know that the things it contains exist in the first place?

Because such a well-defined and existent set such as $\wp(A)$ should not contain nonexistent elements, to prove the existence of its elements is important. It seems that two alternatives arise:

1. Being a member of $\wp(A)$ automatically makes this thing to exist;

or

2. There should be an alternative to prove the existence of all subsets of $A$ without the axiom of power set.

Comment: That's a good question. And in general the is no guarantee a thing exists be its definition. But in this case you are overlooking def. 0. The definition of a set itself. A set is a collection of objects, and objects, existentiallt,... are.  So it is a nature of being a set itself that it must be able to have subsets.  Not by definition of subset but by the empirical nature of a set.  At least that's how I see it.  I realize that's philosophically and ontologically vague.  But there it is.

Comment: I am interpreting this as you asking how we know the subsets of $A$ other than $A$ and $\emptyset$ exist. To answer this, it follows from the axiom of specification. For example $\{a,b\} = \{x \in A : x \neq c\}$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 That only gives you the subsets definable by some predicate. In $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb N)$ there are only countably many of those. What about the others?

Comment: One way to prove the existence of a subset $B$ of $A$ is to apply the *Axiom of Separation* with a suitable formula defining $B$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA See my comment above. To apply Separation you need a predicate, of which there are only countably many.

Comment: See [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).

Comment: The Powerset axiom states that for any set $X$, the powerset of X is also a set -- that is, it *exists*. In ZF(C), to *exist* means *to be a set* means *to be a member of something (else)*.

Comment: @BrianO I thought that might be the case. But I can't help but find this rather disturbing: the existence of a set emerge from a membership relation.

Comment: @BrianO You might want to consider making that an answer! :)

Comment: @Fred Think of it as: a collection is a set if it's not too big (is small enough to be a member of something else, e.g. the singleton of itself, or a powerset, ...).

Comment: Your question is not related to the definition of the power set, but to the definition of the subsets, it seems. So you should provide the latter.

Comment: You're missing $\{b,c\}$.

Comment: "In a simple case where a set A={a,b,c}
{a},{b},{c},{a,b},{a,c},∅
 and A are subsets of A
 and anything different is not."

This is wrong.  It is easily shown that if a set contains n members then it has $2^n$ subsets. {a, b, c} has 3 members so it has $2^3= 8$ subsets, not 7.  As joriki says you are missing {b, c}.

Comment: Ok. Just edited this correction

Comment: Is the set of all things that do not exist, a well-defined set, in the language of set theory?  We should determine whether membership of some set implies existence and this example implies it doesn't.

Comment: @BrianO How do you get around the fact that, by your argument, the members of the set of nonexistent things, all exist?

Comment: @RobertFrost What "fact" is that? There are no "nonexistent things". You (or I) can't define any of them, or the collection of them, in ZF(C).

Comment: @BrianO You appear to be arguing that existence in ZF(C) equates to membership of a set which is a theorem of the axioms, is that correct?

Comment: @RobertFrost More precisely, "..equates to membership **in** a set..." -- basically, yes. This is not controversial. Existence in ZFC of something denoted by a term $t$ with no free variables means $ZFC\vdash \exists x \, t\in x$. There are several equivalent ways to express it, including the more obvious $ZFC\vdash \exists x \, t = x$ -- a "term", after all, is something introduced by definitions, which are strictly speaking just shorthands which can be eliminated. In ZFC, you cannot talk about things that don't *exist* insofar as ZFC is concerned.

Comment: @BrianO The semantics are important here. Does that only mean you can't talk of things that are proven to not exist, or does it also mean you can't talk of things which are not proven to exist?

Comment: @BrianO You may have guessed where I'm heading with this... Does your statement imply, in ZFC, we can't *talk of* a set having cardinality between $\omega_0$ and $\omega_2$.  And if so, what exactly does "can't talk of" mean? I'm trying to focus in on independence from the axioms and its relationship with existence "within ZFC". I'm not currently convinced the notion of "within ZFC" is well-defined.

Comment: @RobertFrost No I wouldn't have guessed you'd suspect anything I said implies that $\omega_1$ doesn't exist. Wherever do you get THAT?  "Within ZFC" is perfectly well-defined, it just means "provable in the theory ZFC". Likewise, there's nothing mystical about "can't talk of".

Comment: @BrianO so the question is;  Does that only mean you can't talk of things that are proven to not exist, or does it also mean you can't talk of things which are not proven to exist?  And what does "can't talk of" mean?

Comment: @BrianO I didn't claim you said $\omega_1$ doesn't exist. I think you misunderstood or didn't read properly.

Comment: @RobertFrost Of course in ZFC we can *define* $\omega_1$ in ZFC, and prove many things about it. Certainly that constitutes "talking about it" in ZFC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41919/discussion-between-robert-frost-and-briano).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The power set axiom just tells you what it says: for every $A$, there exists a set $\mathcal{P}(A)$ such that
$$
\text{for all $B$, $B\in\mathcal{P}(A)$ if and only if $B\subseteq A$}
$$
There is no claim of “existence” of any particular subset of $A$. In $\mathsf{ZFC}$ one can show that $|\mathcal{P}(A)|>|A|$, so there is plenty of subsets.

It should be noted that, if $A$ is infinite, there is no hope to find, for each subset of $A$, a formula “describing it”, because $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is uncountable. This is however not a problem: the axiom tells you that you have a “container” for all subsets of $A$; when you prove that a set $B$ is a subset of $A$, then you know it belongs to $\mathcal{P}(A)$; and conversely, if you pick $B\in\mathcal{P}(A)$, you know $B\subseteq A$.

The real purpose of the axiom is that the subsets of a set form a *set*. In particular, for instance, the equivalence relations on a set form a set that can be isolated from $\mathcal{P}(A\times A)$ using a suitable predicate and the axiom of separation.

I remember some good notes about this in Paul J. Cohen's “Set theory and the continuum hypothesis”.

Comment: But, is there a "claim of existence" of all subsets of $A$ from the axiom?

Comment: @Fred By definition, whatever qualifies as a subset of $A$ belongs to the power *set* of $A$. The axiom says this is a set (that is, it can belong to some other set and you can apply the axiom of replacement to it); it doesn't tell you *how to build* subsets of $A$.

Comment: I see that it doesn't provide any instructions to build subsets, but my question is: can we claim the existence of anything that qualifies as subset of $A$ _because_ it's a member of $\wp (A)$ (known to exist, from the axiom)?

Comment: @Fred In order to say that something belongs to the power set of $A$ you have to *prove* it belongs to it.

Comment: Sure. The question is: if we are talking about some set whose existence we are not sure about; and if we come to prove it belongs to $\wp (A)$ have we _then_ proved its existence?

Comment: @Fred If you prove that something is an element of *any* set, then it is a set. Avoid thinking to “existence” and your life will be easier.

Comment: That's what I wanted to know

Comment: @egreg But we're not looking for an easy life, we're looking for correct mathematics.  This argument doesn't guarantee existence. However it's untrue in ZFC that existence is not implied.  Existence is guaranteed by the axiom of the unordered pair.

Comment: @RobertFrost I'm not sure that's the concept of “existence” the OP is talking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can actually derive what $P(S)$ is for any random $S$, from the axioms. Try to describe $P(\mathbb N)$ for instance.

If you have described a set $P'$ and want to know if $P'=P(S)$, then you can't do much more than try to prove that $$X\in P'\implies X\subset S\\ X\notin P'\implies X\not\subset S.$$ But that's only if you have found a way to describe $P'$, which will not always be possible.

Lastly, $\emptyset$ and $S$ are not the only subsets whose existence is immediate, for any set $S$. It is not very hard to prove the existence of sets with more than one element. This means we can do the following:

Suppose we have a set nonempty $S$ which is not a singleton, i.e. $(\forall x)(\emptyset\neq S\neq\{x\})$. Now, assume that $P(S)=\{\emptyset, S\}$. 
$$x\in S\implies \{x\}\subset S\implies \{x\}=\emptyset \vee \{x\}=S$$ Both $\{x\}=\emptyset$ and $\{x\}=S$ give a contradiction, so there have to be subsets of $S$, other than $\emptyset$ or $S$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Axiom of Extensionality .$\forall x\;\forall y\; (x=y \iff \forall z\;(z\in x \iff z\in y)\;).$
2. Axiom of Pairing. $\forall x \;\forall y\;\exists z\;\forall w\; (w\in z\iff (w=x\lor w=y)\;).$

We write $x=\{y,z\}$ as an abbreviation for $\forall w\;(w\in x\iff (w=y\lor w=z)\;).$ It is is a justifiable abbreviation because of Extensionality. Then the existence of an $x$ satisfying $x=\{y,z\}$ is Pairing.

The Power-Set Axiom by itself cannot imply that anything other than $A$ is a subset of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

The axiom of the unordered pair guarantees existence for every set since it explicitly states that for any set, the union of that set with any other set exsits. So it stipulates that the union of any set with itself exists.  The union of any set with itself is itself, therefore every set exists.

Every subset of the Power Set is a set, therefore every subset of a set exists.

Answer (score -1):

The most relevant axiom is actually the one mentioned by MathematicsStudent1122 and MauroALLEGRANZA, namely the [*Axiom of Separation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) (sometimes called *specification*).  Whenever you have a property expressed for example by a formula, this axiom guarantees that there is a subset whose members are precisely those entities that have the property or satisfy the formula.

For example, you can write down the property of a natural number $n$ that $(\exists m\in\mathbb{N})\,\big(n=2m\big)$ meaning that $n$ is an even integer.  But how do you know that the *set* of even integers exists? That's the role of the separation axiom.

In certain interesting mathematical theories, you can have predicates that do *not* satisfy separation. One such theory is [Nelson's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_set_theory).

Comment: If you read the comments, there is a criticism of this: there are only countably many predicates but  $\mathcal{P} (\mathbb{N})$ is uncountable.

Comment: @Mathematics, by downward Lowenheim-Skolem, there are models of set theory where there will be externally only countably many subsets of N. The OP's problem is a view of foundations that's too realist. I merely gave a possible source of infinitely many subsets, since it is clearly possible to write down infinitely many predicates.